# Не работает свойство transition для background

Tags: css

Есть блок, при клике на который ему через jQuery добавляется класс `.ative`

Почему не работает плавная смена фона при клике? Фон меняется моментально, без анимации.

```js
$(".js-active_column").click(function() {

        $(this).addClass("active");

    });
```

```css
.slot_column {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    
}

.slot_column.active {
    transition: background 2s ease-in-out;
    background: #fed101;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slot_column js-active_column">Текст</div>
```

Comment: дайте весь код, относящийся к данному блоку: разметку, стили и js. То, что вы приложили, ни о чем не говорит. К вопросу всегда необходим [минимальный воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Запустил ваш код, все работает, фон меняется плавно

Comment: Вешайте `transition` на основной класс, а не на `.active`. В ином случае можете получить вот такой баг, когда `background` накладывается резко.